# What was the first canonical event to be referenced in an MCU movie that occurred in non-movie MCU media?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Based on release dates — rather than the in-universe timeline — when was the first time that one of the MCU movies referenced an event that took place in another part of the MCU other than a movie?

For example, an MCU movie referencing something that happened in one of the spinoff TV shows, or a tie-in comic.

Such as one of the movies referencing an event that happened in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law*, or *Loki*.

I'm thinking of something that's explicitly part of the MCU canon as described in Marvel's MCU archive, as opposed to material that originates from Marvel but is outside of the MCU. So, not films like the X-Men or Logan or the 1980s/90s Thor or Hulk movies. Or the Marvel Anime series.

[Official MCU archive](https://www.mcuschedule.com/archive/)

Comment: Earliest I can think of would be in Avengers - Age of Ultron, where Fury brings in the helicarrier provided by Coulson (which he was fixing up in Agents of SHIELD).

Comment: The Afghan War, the very first "event" from the very first MCU movie? What exactly is your definition of a "canonical event"? What are you including in the "franchise"?

Comment: I mean, if your phrase it this broadly, the very first MCU movie would inherently be referring to the pre-MCU Marvel source material.

Comment: In the inhumans series they mentioned Namor to be the first mutant in history, yes?

Comment: @Laurel, a canonical event is any event that's canonical to the MCU. For example, the Thor and Iron Man movies, but not the 1990s X-men cartoon. The Franchise is everything that Marvel includes in the MCU, for example The Falcon Disney Plus series https://www.mcuschedule.com/archive/

Comment: @Flater, as per the original question, this is limited to the MCU, so anything pre MCU, or non canonical to the MCU would be excluded. For example, the Movie Logan would be excluded as it's not part of the MCU, but the modern Thor movies would be included

Comment: @DanielV, I'm looking for the first time that an MCU movie references part of the MCU other than a movie, for example, Black Panther referencing Agents of Shield.

Comment: Expanding on @Flater 's comment, the first MCU movie _Iron Man_ (2008) would have been the first to reference canonical events that happened in another part of the franchise outside of the MCU movies (since there weren't any other movies yet at that time). The second MCU movie to do this would be _The Incredible Hulk_ (2008), which referenced canonical events that were not in _Iron Man_. What I think you are actually asking about is canonical events in MCU films that are not normally associated with the starring character, which had not yet been referenced in any previous MCU films.

Comment: @Steve Pemberton, I'm not asking that at all. I'm asking about events that are part of the e MCU, but aren't from the movies. For example, Agent Carter, Agents of shield, Hakweye, and so on.

Comment: @AaarghZombies: Some of the things (a fair few of them, really) that happen in the MCU also have happened before the MCU was established, i.e. in the pre-MCU Marvel material. Either pre-MCU Marvel is a valid reference, or you should restrict your question to specifically ask for a reference to something that is **exclusive to the non-movie MCU** (e.g. rephrase your question to _"an event that took place in another part of the **non-movie** MCU **and nowhere else**"_), which would then exclude pre-MCU Marvel. Because if it happens in MCU _and_ pre-MCU, how would you distinguish it?

Comment: @Flater, But .... that's exactly what I've been asking for. When was the firdt time an MCU movie referenced another part ofthe MCU that wasn't a movie. I even provided examples such as Agents of Shield and She-Hulk. I'm not sure how much clearer I can be on this. I even provided a link the MCU archive which contains all of the MCU sources.

Comment: If *"All Hail the King"* is considered non-movie, then it's *Shang-Chi*, which is Sept. 2021.  If *Daredevil* is considered part of the criteria, then it's *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, which is December 2021.  Otherwise, it's *Doctor Strange & TMoM* for referencing *Wandavision*, which is 2022.

Comment: Also, does "backsplaining" count?  We're still waiting on confirmation regarding the identities of "a high school valedictorian in Iowa City" and "a TV anchor in Cairo" which Sitwell references as threats (alongside Stephen Strange and Bruce Banner) identified by Project Insight during *Captain America: Winter Soldier* (April 4, 2014).

Answer (score 2):

#### *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* referencing *WandaVision*

One of the first, if not the first, instances of an MCU movie referencing a canonical event that occurred in non-movie MCU media was in the movie *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), which directly referenced and acknowledged the events of the TV series *WandaVision* (2021).

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, both Wanda Maximoff and Doctor Strange explicitly mentioned the name of the town, Westview, where the majority of the events of *WandaVision* took place. In *WandaVision*, Wanda created a reality-altering barrier around Westview, known as the "Hex" or the "Westview anomaly". The movie explored the consequences of Wanda’s actions in *WandaVision* in connection to the multiverse.

---

##### *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* referencing *All Hail the King*

(I added this part second, as this may not satisfy your criteria since you may be excluding references to short films.)

Another possible answer to this question is the events in the short film [*All Hail the King*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Hail_the_King) (2014), which feature Trevor Slattery being broken out of prison by a Ten Rings (organization) operative. This is later referenced in the movie *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* (2021), where we learn that Trevor was actually captured by the Ten Rings after they freed him from prison.

Answer (score 0):

#### *Spider-Man: No Way Home* referencing Netflix *Daredevil*

*Spider-Man: No Way Home* was released in the United States on December 17, 2021.  In one scene, the actor Charlie Cox reprises his role as Matthew Murdock (aka Daredevil), the titular character from the Netflix streaming series *Daredevil*, which premiered on April 10, 2015.  Prior to this instance, there have been no references by the MCU to any of the Netflix properties.

Whether this is the exact same Daredevil from the Netflix show or if the Netflix series took place in a timeline variant from the MCU remains to be explained by Marvel Entertainment.  The upcoming *Daredevil: Born Again* may explain where "Netflix *Daredevil*" sits in respect to the MCU, as subsequent appearances of characters from the series (in Disney+ *Hawkeye* and *She-Hulk* series) have not validated anything.  Alternately, the Disney+ *Echo* series, which includes "Netflix *Daredevil*" characters, may explain the relation to the Netflix series earlier than *Born Again*.

Regardless, *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* was released September 3, 2021, beating *Spider-Man: No Way Home* by a few months, unless *All Hail the King* is not considered a "spin-off TV show".

Answer (score 0):

**Nick Fury referencing events of Agents Of S.H.I.E.L.D. in Avengers: Age Of Ultron**

I added this as a comment but wasn't sure whether it would count, due to:

1 - ambiguity

2 - whether AoS is actually canon

In any case, during season 2 of Agents Of S.H.I.E.L.D. (AoS, I'm not typing all that again), much of Phil Coulson's time is spent trying to fix up a helicarrier - the same one that Nick Fury uses in Avengers: Age Of Ultron (though he credits "an old friend", if I recall correctly).

Now, why shouldn't this count? It is never explicitly explained who this "old friend" is, and though AoS is definitely a thing that happened, how canonical it is (what with it not acknowledging "the snap", though this is mainly due to the movie studios making demands) is pretty up in the air. But at the time, it was meant to be canonical and following the movie storylines.

Comment: What Fury said was: "I pulled her out of mothballs with a couple of old friends." The 'old friends' are just the people on board the helicarrier, like the agent from CA:TWS (agent Klein). In AoS, they made a cool connection with Coulson being the one supplying the helicarrier, but for the movies it doesn't matter where it came from.